# SQL: Como Contar valores em colunas diferentes

Tags: sql, postgresql

Gostaria de saber como contar valores em colunas diferentes.
Exemplo genérico:

```
ID - COLUNA1 - COLUNA2
1  - foo     - Bar
2  -         - Foo
3  - Qux     - Bar
4  - Bar     -
```

Eu espero como resultado

```
count - value
2     - Foo
3     - Bar
1     - Qux
```

Att,
Alexandre.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Para fazer este select que você precisa primeiro você terá que mesclar as duas colunas. Você pode usar o comando **UNION ALL** que faz a soma dos resultados (assim como os duplicados) de 2 ou mais resultados.

Depois disso, você precisa fazer uma contagem dessa seleção usando o **HAVING**. Também percebo que você não quer os campos que estão vazios portanto você pode excluir os mesmos da contagem na função **HAVING**, Assim:

```
SELECT  --seleção sobre o resultado do union
    COUNT(colunas) AS NUM_REG, 
    colunas AS SUM_COL
FROM
    (SELECT LOWER(COLUNA1) AS COLUNAS FROM TABELA   
     UNION ALL
     SELECT LOWER(COLUNA2) AS COLUNAS FROM TABELA
    ) nomeDoSelect --necessário nomear o union para funcinonar
GROUP BY
    colunas
HAVING COUNT(colunas) > 0 AND colunas != '' --excluindo células vazias
```

Assim você terá o resultado:

```
+---------+---------+
| NUM_REG | SUM_COL |
+---------+---------+
|    3    |   bar   |
|    2    |   foo   |
|    1    |   qux   |
+---------+---------+
```

> Note que na seleção eu fiz com que as seleções do UNION sejam
>   transformadas para lowecase, porque dependendo do COLLATION do seu
>   banco de dados, o resultado pode ser diferente (ex de colation que
>   precisa de transformar para o lower: `utf8_unicode_cs`)

Comment: Obrigado! Deu certo :D